# Ciphertext using XOR displaying binary and decimal numbers

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, caesar-cipher

I am having troubles understanding how to XOR my two outputs. The program is having the user input their own plaintext and key. For example the user would input "bad" and "fed" for their 2 inputs. The program is then going to convert each character of the PT and K to the binary and decimal number representation. I have that part working in my code. The problem i am having is that when i try using XOR or ^  it says i am getting an error in my executable. I think i need to store the binary representation of each character first and then ill be able XOR the two? The XOR'd output should be in binary and decimal form. Any help??

The last two lines of code is how i am trying to implement XOR

The error which i am receiving is : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) 
for ^: 'str' and 'str'

```
key = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzz0123456789'

def encrypt(n, plaintext):
    """Encrypt the string and return the ciphertext"""
    result = ''

for l in plaintext.lower():
    try:
        i = (key.index(l) + n) % 26
        result += key[i]
    except ValueError:
        result += l

return result.lower()

def decrypt(n, ciphertext):
"""Decrypt the string and return the plaintext"""
result = ''

for l in ciphertext:
    try:
        i = (key.index(l) - n) % 26
        result += key[i]
    except ValueError:
        result += l

return result

plaintext = input('Enter Plaintext: ')
k = input('Enter Key Varaible:')

offset = 5

encrypted = encrypt(offset, plaintext)
#print('Encrypted:', encrypted)

decrypted = decrypt(offset, encrypted)
#print('Decrypted:', decrypted)

print("Decimal and Binary number representation of PT")
print(["{0} {0:06b} ".format(ord(c)-ord('a')) for c in plaintext])
print("Decimal and Binary number representation of K")
print(["{0} {0:06b} ".format(ord(c)-ord('a')) for c in k])
print(["{0:06b} ".format(ord(c)-ord('a')) for c in k])

playing = True
while playing:
choice = input("Would you like to see the encrypted PT? y/n: ")
if choice == "n":
    #print("Thanks for running my program")
    playing = False
else:
    print("Encrypted Result:" + encrypted)

playing = True
while playing:
choice = input("Would you like to see the decrypted PT? y/n: ")
if choice == "n":
    #print("Thanks for running my program")
    playing = False
else:
    print("Decrypted Result:" + decrypted)

CT = (plaintext ^ k)
print("Ciphertext : " + CT)
```

Comment: What does the error say exactly

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' add 'str'

Answer (score 0):

You print the converted value of K out but never actually update K to the new value. So you're performing XOR with a string and not an int. Just add `k = bin(k)`

Comment: wouldn't i need to do this to plaintext also?

Comment: @JacobGellhaus a char is fundamentally a binary number but python I think does make a distinction so yes you should

Comment: I made those changes, this is the error i am still getting  -               
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'fed'

Comment: @JacobGellhaus it must want base 2 then, try bin()

Comment: Both `plaintext` and `k` are strings. He needs to `ord()` each char first, and then iterate through them applying the xor key.

Comment: print(["{0} {0:06b} ".format(ord(c)-ord('a')) for c in plaintext]) this allows me to ouput ['1 000001 ', '0 000000 ', '3 000011 '] which is the answer i need. Now i  just need to be able to take this output and XOR it with the other output. Does this mean i need to ord() it again?